How to extract the directory (e.g., es/ or pt/) from the pathname to dynamically update the heading in a custom web component?
I am working on a custom web component and want to dynamically manipulate the heading in my Carousel component based on the directory in the URL pathname (e.g., es/ for Spanish or pt/ for Portuguese).
class Carousel extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `
      <div class="Carousel-Sec">
        <p class="trusted-brands-heading">
          <!-- Heading template -->
        </p>
        <!-- Image template -->
      </div>
    `;
  }
}



You can dynamically set the heading in your Carousel component by parsing the URL pathname and then assigning the appropriate heading text based on the detected language directory.
class Carousel extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const languageHeadings = {
      es: 'Marcas de confianza', // Spanish
      pt: 'Marcas confiáveis',  // Portuguese
      en: 'Trusted Brands',     // Default to English
    };

    // Extract the language directory from the URL pathname
    const pathname = window.location.pathname;
    const langMatch = pathname.match(/^\/(es|pt)\//);
    const lang = langMatch ? langMatch[1] : 'en'; // Default to English if no match

    // Set the heading text based on the language
    const headingText = languageHeadings[lang];

    // Inject the component's HTML with the dynamic heading
    this.innerHTML = `
      <div class="Carousel-Sec">
        <p class="trusted-brands-heading">
          ${headingText}
        </p>
        <!-- Add image or other templates here -->
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

// Define the custom element
customElements.define('custom-carousel', Carousel);

